# Table Structure for adding group table and related with existing post table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using following table

```
user(id,name,mailid,password,....);//Contains user info

post(id,message,sender_id,receiver_id,...);//user post stores here
```

Now I want to include group feature 
for that I have created group tables

```
group(id,name,description,...);
group_member(group_id,user_id,role);
```

Here I am not able to  relate post with group
Is above table design is correct?
How can I use same post table for 
user and group?
Or should I make different table for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the case is that post is related to one group only (as I understand this is the case) to can add foreign key to post table for reference to group table :

```
post(id,message,sender,receiver,group_id...)
```

if post can have multiple groups related to it so add table like

```
group_post(post_id,group_id)
```

Comment: So shuold I have to add a field for `group_id`?

Comment: If the relation is one-to-many between post and group (post can be related only to one group) so add group_id field  in post table.if the relation is one-to-one so add group_id as foreign or post_id as foreign key. if the relation is many-to-many e.g post can have multiple groups related and groups can have multiple post so add a new table

Comment: Here I aslo want to to ant msg belong to group can share with user and and message of share can send to group is it possible with above??

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. Try to be more clear

Comment: Message posting from group to user and use t group is possible??